# How did Nagato have his eyes before Madara’s death during the 2nd Shinobi war?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto Shippuden*, Nagato had his Rinnegan during the 2nd Shinobi war. However, it is said Madara implanted his Rinnegan in Nagato right before his death, but Madara’s death was during or after the 3rd Shinobi war.

So how did Nagato have his eyes before Madara’s death during the 2nd Shinobi war? I’m confused with the timeline of when he actually got the Rinnegan.

Answer (score 1):

Madara implanted the Rinnegan onto Nagato when he was very young. And this was done without Nagato's knowledge. Then the Second Shinobi War started, after a while.

After implanting the eyes, Madara waited for years to find a person who could be used as a tool. This "tool" was supposed to guide Nagato to properly use the Rinnegan at the right time, bringing Madara back alive, at his prime state.

So in order to find a suitable "tool", Madara connected himself with the Gedo Statue and siphoned it's life essence. He would die the moment he disconnected, as he was far past his natural death.

Madara then died after finding Obito, training him and handing over his name.

Comment: Thank you answering. But Madara still had Rinnegan in one of his eyes when he met Obito.

Comment: No he did not have Rinnegan when he met kid Obito. He had Sharingan. Those eyes were not his original eyes. Just some replacement eyes. If you're talking about the Fourth Shinobi War, those were edo tensei eyes.